# Increasing tabBarItem image size

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

okay so i am programatically adding the images to my tabbaritems like so

```
self.button1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"156-controlpad.png"];
```

I am wondering if there is a way to increase the size of the images from the 30x30 "what they normally are" to something larger like 45x45.. or is all that is required is a bigger image?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just found the answer, Interface builders ruler has image insets you can change for tabbaritems... last place I thought to look as I thought the ruler would have button sizes or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Image strip on App Window.